# How to not stretch an image in UIButton background

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, uibutton, scale

I have an uibutton which size is 100x100 and background image size is not same height and width so that image is stretching. How can i prevent this situation i set the background image like this;

[lc_button setBackgroundImage:location_background forState:UIControlStateNormal]

PS..I don't want to use setImage since other problems. i now that imageEdgeInsets and set image it work.

Comment: why dont you use the aspect fit mode ?

Comment: Like @TejaNandamuri mentioned, have you tried changing the contentMode of your button's imageView? Aspect fit or Aspect Fill sounds like the answer

Comment: You can use slicing option of Assets.xcassets. For more details, open this URL: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/SlicinganImage.html

Comment: resize the image based on button frame size and add again